# Store view access

Tags: magento-1.9, login, store-view

I would like to have a custom log in for my second store view. Store view B will only accept .gov, .mil, and .edu emails. Here is what I envision.

Client A goes to our site and sees two store views. A and B. Client A should only be able to create an account on for store view A because he only has a .com email. I want to make sure after he creates his account for store view A, he cannot view Store view B. Is this possible on a store view level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this extension:
http://www.itoris.com/magento-login-management.html

I have used it previously and I think it has what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I believe this extension will work for me.